# Remove the last 2 elements from each index in a Multidimensional Array

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

How do I loop through a multidimensional array and remove the last 2 elements of each index?
So in this example, I would remove `Edit` & `Delete` from each of the indexes. I tried pop and slice methods but wasn't quite getting the results that I needed

[image]

This is the result I'm trying to get in an array.
[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>


<body>

<div class="container">
      
  <table class="table table-bordered" id="table_id">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>col-1</th>
        <th>col-2</th>
        <th>col-3</th>
        <th>col-4</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="edit_btn">Edit</button></td>               
        <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="delete_btn">Delete</button></td>
        
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Mary</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="edit_btn">Edit</button></td>               
        <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="delete_btn">Delete</button></td>
        
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>July</td>
        <td>9</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="edit_btn">Edit</button></td>               
        <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="delete_btn">Delete</button></td>
        
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

<script>
var table_row = [];
var myArray = [];


$('#table_id tr').each(function(index, tr) {
    
    table_row = $('td', tr).map(function(index, td) {   
        return $(td).text();
    });
    // Here table_row will contain an array of all td values for the current row:
    // like ['value 1', 'value 2', 'value 3']
    

myArray.push(table_row);
});

console.log(myArray);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Barmar I see thanks for clearing that up. I'm trying to put all the text except for edit and delete into an array for later use when I need to loop through it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$('td', tr).map()` returns a jQuery collection, not an array, but it's an array-like object. You can call `.get()` to get a real array from that.

To remove the last two elements, you can use `.slice()`. Giving it a negative end index counts from the end of the array.

So change

```
myArray.push(table_row);
```

to

```
myArray.push(table_row.get().slice(0, -2));
```

You could also just change your loop to only process the first 3 `td` on each row.

```
var table_row = $('td:lt(3)', tr).map(...).get();
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to remove the last 2 indexes from each array.
Here is an example:

Sample Array:

```
const a = [
  [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],
  [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],
  [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],
  [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],
  [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],
  [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],
]
```

And then do this to the array:

```
const list = a.map(item => {
    const updatedList = item.splice(0, item.length - 2);
    return updatedList;
  })
```